# Groovy Power Assert Statement Output

Tags: groovy, assert

I'm using Spock and hate hard asserts for functional tests.  I've written a SoftAssert class and everything works, I just want to make it look more like Groovy's power asserts.

Here is my existing method:

```
public void verifyEquals(def expected, def actual, String message = '') {
    try {
        assert expected == actual
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
        LOGGER.warn("Verification failed, expected: ${expected.toString()} but got ${actual}.\n ${message}")
        softAssertList.add(new SoftAssert(message, e))
    }
}
```

I'm just catching the failure, simple enough.  Now what is lacking is the nice output that Groovy does so well.  Instead of the statements I pass into verifyEquals such as: `verifyEquals(8, (3 + x) * z)`

```
8 == (3 + x) * z
  |     | |  | |
  |     | 0  | |
  |     3    | 2
  |          6
false
```

I get `expected == actual`

```
expected == actual
   |     |    |
   8     |    6
       false
```

This happens because the statement is calculated prior to passing it into the method.  Does anyone know how to keep the test in the format of `verifyEquals(8, (3 + x) * z)` while passing in the parameters and how to keep the Power Assert error from the original parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `verify` method should accept a `Closure` (code block) containing the assertion, execute it, and store any exception thrown. Usage then looks as follows: `verify { assert 8 == (3 + x) * z }`.

If you annotate the method with Spock's `@ConditionBlock` annotation and put it in a place where Spock can find it at compile time (e.g. base class), the `assert` keyword can even be omitted.

Note that Spock's conditions aren't the same as Groovy's power asserts. If you catch Spock's `ConditionNotSatisfiedError`, you'll get further information about the assertion (e.g. a full syntax tree), which you can exploit to provide better feedback. If you don't need this additional information, then catching `AssertionError` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer is a little bit off topic, but this question was the closest to what I was searching for here and I want to share my own findings. I found this pattern quite useful when using Spock:

```
try {
  assert myPage.myField.text() == "field valueXXX"
}
catch (ConditionNotSatisfiedError e) {
  // Enrich Groovy PowerAssertion with additional text
  def condition = e.condition
  throw new ConditionNotSatisfiedError(
    new Condition(
      condition.values,
      condition.text,
      condition.position,
      "Attention, the Selenium driver obviously cannot delete the session cookie " +
        "JSESSIONID_MY_PROJECT because of 'http-only'!\n" +
        "Please deploy my.project.mobile.smoke instead of my.project.mobile."
    )
  )
}
```

The error log looks like this:

```
Condition not satisfied:

myPage.myField.text() == "field value"
|         |       |      |
|         |       |      false
|         |       |      3 differences (78% similarity)
|         |       |      field value(---)
|         |       |      field value(XXX)
|         |       field valueXXX
|         myField - SimplePageContent (owner: my.project.module.geb.pages.MyPage, args: [], value: null)
my.project.module.AdminPage

Attention, the Selenium driver obviously cannot delete the session cookie JSESSIONID_MY_PROJECT because of 'http-only'!
Please deploy my.project.mobile.smoke instead of my.project.mobile.

Expected :field valueXXX
Actual   :field value

  <Click to see difference>

    at my.project.module.MySampleIT.#testName(MySampleIT.groovy:57)
```